# Numpy loadtxt function

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy

The code I am using is:

```
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\data.csv',delimiter=",")
```

why is this not working
I copied the data.csv file in the above specified location and it did not work.

I copied the csv file in the jupyter folder, but it still  did not work
What is wrong?
I'm using python 3.

The error that I am getting is

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-498d125dea5e> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 da=np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\data.csv',delimiter=",")
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin)
   1022 
   1023             # Convert each value according to its column and store
-> 1024             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1025             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting
   1026             items = pack_items(items, packing)~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1022 
   1023             # Convert each value according to its column and store
-> 1024             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1025             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting
   1026             items = pack_items(items, packing)~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in floatconv(x)
    723         if b'0x' in x:
    724             return float.fromhex(asstr(x))
--> 725         return float(x)
    726 
    727     typ = dtype.type
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'"32.502345269453"'
```

Comment: please help me resolve this concern only..  providing alternate approach to load csv file is not needed.. thankyou

Comment: If you want help, you actually have to tell us what is wrong.  Don't just say it doesn't work.  What is happening?  Any error messages?  Any results?

Comment: I think the bug already edited by @hpaulj ; the fix could be `loadtext` to `loadtxt`.

Comment: please see the error.. i am using np.loadtxt only..  thanks\

Comment: Looks like the numbers are quoted.  `loadtxt` can't handle those directly.

Comment: @hpaulj  please reconsider the question as i have made some changes  .. thankyou for the feedback

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VPxiHyoi6wo9yPAuC7A1JBB0aIZdWgY6                                                          google drive link for the csv file

Answer (score 0):

numpy doesn't support the usual quotechar setting, but you could still read it in by borrowing Python's CSV library as follows:

```
import csv    
import numpy as np

with open('data.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    data = np.genfromtxt((','.join(row) for row in csv.reader(f_input)), delimiter=',')

print(data)
```

Giving you data like:

```
[[ 32.50234527  31.70700585]
 [ 53.42680403  68.77759598]
 [ 61.53035803  62.5623823 ]
 [ 47.47563963  71.54663223]
 ...
 [ 49.23976534  72.11183247]
 [ 50.03957594  85.23200734]
 [ 48.14985889  66.22495789]
 [ 25.12848465  53.45439421]]
```